# HTML Div not expanding when table has width

Tags: html, html-table, width, expand

I'm using a div in which a table resides.
The table has no width on my page but it grows.

As a test I have tried to set the width on a table inside a div, the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22ES5/).

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;margin:0 50px;">
<div>
<table style="border:1px solid red; width:1000px;">
<tr><td style="white-space: nowrap;">hej</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? 
E.g. the div should span its width to make the table fit inside?

Comment: "The table has no with on my page", so what is width:1000px; on table?

Comment: The table has no set width on my real page. but in order for you to see what i mean the example table has a set width. and the problem is the same. the table grows larger than the div

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width in `%age` as

```
width:100%
```

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/22ES5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

If you dont give any width to your inner table, and go on adding the content, it works perfectly fine.

Here is a [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/22ES5/4/).

The CODE:

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;margin:0 50px;">
<div>
<table style="border:1px solid red;">
<tr><td>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.